# Skin VScrollBar from a TextArea

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, flex4.5, flex4.6

This is the question: How can i Skin the VScrollBar from a TextArea!? I did skin a VScrollBar from a Spark List and works fine but not this one!!
Any help!?
Thanks ;-)

Comment: Which TextArea do you use - Spark or MX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the skin using a stylesheet that sets all scrollbars within your chosen textareas to use your skin. For example, use this directive:

```
.scrollableText s|VScrollBar
{
    skin-class: ClassReference("com.net.org.skins.ScrollBarSkin");
}
```

To skin this textarea:

```
<s:TextArea styleName="scrollableText">
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks; but one problem persists.. the scrollThumb doesn't scroll over the 100% of the track!!